# Python iterating through a json array of a dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, python-requests

I apologize for the fairly basic question, but I seem to be struggling to iterate through anything other than the keys on this JSON array/dictionary.

```
import requests

villager_url = requests.get("https://acnhapi.com/v1/villagers")
villagers = villager_url.json()

for villager in villagers:
    print(villager)
```

the request is set up pretty basic and right now I can get a list of the keys, but I am struggling to print out anything that is contained within the array that makes up the value of the dictionary.

```
{
"ant00": {
"id": 1,
"file-name": "ant00",
"name": {
"name-USen": "Cyrano",
"name-EUen": "Cyrano",
"name-EUde": "Theo",
"name-EUes": "Cirano",
"name-USes": "Cirano",
"name-EUfr": "Cyrano",
"name-USfr": "Cyrano",
"name-EUit": "Cirano",
"name-EUnl": "Cyrano",
"name-CNzh": "阳明",
"name-TWzh": "陽明",
"name-JPja": "さくらじま",
"name-KRko": "사지마",
"name-EUru": "Сирано"
},
"personality": "Cranky",
"birthday-string": "March 9th",
"birthday": "9/3",
"species": "Anteater",
"gender": "Male",
"subtype": "B",
"hobby": "Education",
"catch-phrase": "ah-CHOO",
"icon_uri": "https://acnhapi.com/v1/icons/villagers/1",
"image_uri": "https://acnhapi.com/v1/images/villagers/1",
"bubble-color": "#194c89",
"text-color": "#fffad4",
"saying": "Don't punch your nose to spite your face.",
"catch-translations": {
"catch-USen": "ah-CHOO",
"catch-EUen": "ah-CHOO",
"catch-EUde": "schneuf",
"catch-EUes": "achús",
"catch-USes": "achús",
"catch-EUfr": "ATCHOUM",
"catch-USfr": "ATCHOUM",
"catch-EUit": "ett-CCIÙ",
"catch-EUnl": "ha-TSJOE",
"catch-CNzh": "有的",
"catch-TWzh": "有的",
"catch-JPja": "でごわす",
"catch-KRko": "임돠",
"catch-EUru": "апчхи"
}
}
}
```

above is the json of the first two key-value pairs. I'm just trying to be able to return a value buried in the value part of the dictionary. I'm mostly looking to return things like the name-USen or possibly a pair of data from the values with the ultimate goal to have a basic web app that will like you put in your birthday and get paired with a villager or something similar. I'm sure this is a no brainer for a lot of you so i apologize. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is to help you:

```
import requests

villager_url = requests.get("https://acnhapi.com/v1/villagers")
villagers = villager_url.json()

dct = {villagers[k]["name"]["name-EUen"]:villagers[k]["birthday-string"] for k in villagers.keys()}

print(dct)
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. if I wanted to look up this process to see how it is working what should I check? I thought it looked like dict comprehension, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @cerealfordinner Yes, it is dict comprehension.